# JQuery : Play notification sound : IE8 Error

Tags: javascript

This code works perfect for crome and firefox.. but error in IE8

```
if($('#soundcheck').is(':checked')){
                    //alert('checked');
                    var audio = document.createElement('audio');
                    document.body.appendChild(audio);
                    audio.src = system_base_url+'/sound/horn.wav';
                    audio.play();

                  }
```

IE8 says: Object doesn't support this property or method, and it points to :

```
audio.play();
```

Anyone having similar experience with IE8?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

The `<audio>` tag is HTML5 and is only supported in newer browsers, such as Internet Explorer 9, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.

Answer (score 2):

IE 8 and earlier does not support Audio tag, you need to use some hack.
Hope it can help.

```
<audio id='audio' controls>
      <source src="audioes/song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
      <source src="audioes/song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
      <div>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio</div>
      <%--Fall back on the WMP plugin--%>
      <object id='mediaPlayer' type="audio/mpeg" width="200" height="40"><param name="src" value="audioes/song.mp3" /></object>
</audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
function play () {
    var audio = document.getElementByID('audio');
    var mediaPlayer = document.getElementByID('mediaPlayer');
    //HTML5 Audio is Supported
    if(audio['play']) 
    {
    audio.play();
    }
    //HTML5 Audio is NOT Supported
    else
    {
    mediaPlayer.object.play();
    }
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem! Try:

```
 <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="playSound('sound.mp3');">...</a>



<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function playSound(soundfile) {
  document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=
  "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: oops! forgot to paste that part, sorry my bad

Comment: working fine.. but.. if i play .wav file.. in crome it says to update quick time plugin.. and in IE it is also asking for the same.. what audio format doesn't not require any Quicktime of anything like that?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think ogg and mp3